# Would someone check my work using cdf method to find the density function?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, density-function

### Problem:

Let Y be a random variable with pdf $$ f_{y}(y) = 2(1-y) \quad 0 < y<1$$ Using the cdf method, find the density function of $U_1 = 2Y-1$.

This seems straightforward, but I would be appreciative if someone would check my work.

### My work

Steps:

1. Identify the CDF
2. Take the derivative of said CDF

---

Step 1:
\begin{align}
F_{U_1}(u_1) &= P(U_1 \le u_1)  \\
&= P\left(Y \le \dfrac{u_1 + 1}{2}\right) \\
&= \int_{0}^{{(u_{1} + 1)}/{2}} 2(1-y) \space dy \\
&= 2\int_{0}^{{(u_{1} + 1)}/{2}} dy - 2\int_{0}^{{(u_{1} + 1)}/{2}} y \space dy \\
&= 2\bigg[y\bigg]_{0}^{{(u_{1} + 1)}/{2}} - 
2 \left[\frac{y^2}{2}\right]_{0}^{{(u_{1} + 1)}/{2}}
\end{align}

This should work out to be

$$
F_{U_1}(u_1) = u_1 + 1 - \frac{(u_1 + 1)^2}{2} = \frac{1}{2}(-u^2 + 1)
$$

---

Step 2:

$ \frac{dF(u_{1})}{du} = \frac{1}{2}(-2u_{1}) = -u_{1}$, so
\begin{cases}
f_{U_1}(u_1) = -u_1 \quad -1 < u_1 < 1, \\
f_{U_1}(u_1) = 0 \quad \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}

I think I may have made an error when doing the range. If $ u > 0$ then the value will be less than 0 and cannot be a probability, so my range should go from -1 to 0? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure and range are correct, you just made a mistake when calculating the integral.
$$
F_{U_1}(u_1) = \int_{0}^{\frac{u_1 + 1}{2}} 2(1-y) dy = \frac{1}{4} (3 + 2u_1 - u_1^2)
$$
and
$$
f_{U_1}(u_1) = \frac{1}{4}( 2 - 2u_1), \quad -1 < u_1 < 1
$$

Comment: whoops.... Thank you, I see my mistake.!